# Maven build fail: "invalid target release" only in GitLab CI

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Part of my GitLab CI pipeline uses Maven ( `mvn test` ). Maven fails to build my test project with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project GenericTests: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 13 -> [Help 1]
```

I did some research and apparently setting `JAVA_HOME` to the location of JDK 13 would work, and it does, but only when I do it by hand locally via SSH.

In my pipeline, even if I export `JAVA_HOME` right before running `mvn test` I still get the same error.

```
script:
     - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-13.0.2
     - mvn test
```

Why does this work differently between GitLab CI and SSH? Could it have to do with the fact that GitLab CI is a non-interactive shell? What can I do to remedy this?

EDIT: I also tried to add a `release` tag in `pom.xml` like so:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <release>13</release>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but this only resulted in another error during build time:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project GenericTests: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Assign variable and run bash command in one line and see if that works. JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-13.0.2 mvn test

Comment: Also in which runner is this running on? If shared runners, are you using the right image and set it up properly? If custom runner, is it set up properly?

Comment: @Macindows It's a specific runner with a shell executor. I will now try your suggestion

Comment: @Macindows Unfortunately your solution didn't work in my case, the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a mess-up on my part: `mvn test` was being executed by means of an alias, which was actually `sudo mvn test`. Hence why the environment variable wasn't being used and why I got Mojo permission denied errors locally when I tried to rerun tests.